# Git-hub issue: Shows 87 files changed of my laravel project

Tags: laravel, github

I am new to git-hub and when I create a pull request it shows a large amount of file changed, I am working on Laravel5 and being a trainee in a company I have to send the PR to my team head. So, How to save a  fresh Laravel file in master branch and then after doing 1 or 2 changes I commit and generate PR?

> Showing  87 changed files  with 834 additions and 2,357 deletions

Answer (score 0):

First, if you generate a PR, do so from a dedicated branch, not from master.

Second, whenever you are pushing to a fork (to make a PR), rebase your local branch first on top of the original repo branch.

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream

git checkout mybranch      # in your case, for now master
git rebase upstream/master # rebase on top of the destination branch
                           # which will receive and integrate your PR

git push --force origin mybranch
```

Then make your PR: the diff will be only your work, as opposed to a delta representing evolution on upstream done while you were preparing your fix.